# What is funeral law of Buddhism?

Tags: lay-buddhism, general-buddhism

What is funeral law of Buddhism is there any ? For both layman and monk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is some information about funerals at this [link](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/kariyawasam/wheel402.html#ch5).

When I lived in a forest monastery in Thailand, dead monks & residents were cremated on a pile of wood in the forest & we would practise meditation on the burning corpse.

[image]